# What are the advantages of using sprites over individual images?

Tags: image, sprite, css-sprites

I recently noticed that every image on this website - the logo, badge colors, up/down voting arrows — the list goes on - are actually part of a single sprite sheet, set as a background image, and repositioned based on the required state. What is the advantage of using this method over using multiple images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a sprite, the browser only has to make one HTTP request for the whole image, instead of N requests for N images. There is significant overhead and delay to creating the TCP connection (three-way handshake), so limiting this to just one request saves a lot of time.

Comment: But with the speed at which most Internet connections currently function, isn't the lag created by multiple requests negligible?

Comment: @JulesMazur not at all. Most connections aren't really "fast", they just have a lot of bandwidth. There is still the significant latency (actual packet delay) for each packet.

Comment: It's also not just about speed but server resources. Every operating system have limits on the number of sockets that can be opened at one time. Beyond that and the server will start rejecting requests. On OSes like Linux this can be increased but there is still a limit (the universe is not infinite after all, much less the RAM in your server). For small sites with few visitors you're right, it is negligible. For a site like StackOverflow it's the difference between needing 2 servers and needing 20.

Answer (score 2):

Simple. You're sending less HTTP requests. One for all images, as opposed to one for each image.

Answer (score 2):

Additionally, a large compressed sprite including all images can be compressed better, resulting in a smaller filesize than all the images on their own. E.g. if you have 10 files that are 20kB in size each, the sprite would normally be much less than 200kB.